# Mathematica does not evaluate the integral

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

I have the following Mathematica Code, But it does not give me anything as the output. Can someone help me.

```
\[Alpha] = 3;
 F[s_] := Exp[-A*s^(2/\[Alpha])]; 
 integral = Re[Assuming[{A > 0, t > 0, {t, A} \[Element] Reals}, 
 Integrate[F[s]*Exp[s*t] /. s -> I*y, {y, 0, Infinity}]/Pi]]
```

I also want to run the following code:

```
\[Alpha] = 4;
 f[s_] := Exp[-A*s^(2/\[Alpha])]; 
 integral =Re[Assuming[{A > 0, t > 0, {t, A} \[Element] Reals}, 
 Integrate[f[s]*Exp[s*t] /. s -> I*y, {y, -Infinity, Infinity}]/Pi]]
```

here A is give by

```
A = Pi*\[Lambda]*P^(2/\[Alpha])*Gamma[1 + 2/\[Alpha]]*Gamma[1 - 2/\[Alpha]];
```

Lambda and P are known values.

Answer (score 0):

At least under version 10 this seems to work

```
α = 3;
A = Pi*λ*P^(2/α)*Gamma[1+2/α]*Gamma[1-2/α];
integral = Re[Assuming[{A > 0, t > 0},
   Integrate[Exp[-A*(I*y)^(2/α)]*Exp[I*y*t], {y, 0, Infinity}]]/Pi]

α = 4;
A = Pi*λ*P^(2/α)*Gamma[1+2/α]*Gamma[1-2/α];
integral = Re[Assuming[{A > 0, t > 0},
  Integrate[Exp[-A*(I*y)^(2/α)]*Exp[I*y*t], {y, -Infinity, Infinity}]]/Pi]
```

If you can provide more information about the values of P and λ then perhaps Re can do more.